# How to get a value of a column from another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas. And recently I have been stuck on a question.

I need to find the name who has the lowest score. But i just don't know how.

df =

```
   name   score  subject
0  Amy    100
1  Amy    99
3  Amy    95
4  Bob    98
5  Bob    88
6  Bob    85
7  Cathy  94
8  Cathy  87 
9  Cathy  90
```

It would be so great if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min()` function

```
df.loc[df.score==df.score.min(), 'name']
```

Comment: Use == and not a single =

Comment: Thank you very much, it solves my question :)